# Force Struts1 to use the correct encoding for the resource file

Tags: windows, encoding, java, struts-1

Seems like the Struts1 uses `InputStream` to read i18n resource file(s) instead of a `Reader`.
There is a `struts.i18n.encoding` property in the Struts2, but I could not find a similar settings for the Struts1.
**Is there a way to force Struts1 into reading resource file(s) using a specific encoding?**

Also I've noticed that in the Russian version of Windows, the `InputStream` uses 'Windows-1251' encoding. However on the English version of Windows (even when the current language for non-Unicode programs is set to Russian), the Java's `InputStream` (and Struts1) uses ANSI encoding.

Java's `-Dfile.encoding` property effects `Reader`, but not the `InputStream` :( Is there another way (maybe by setting some system variable), to **force the Java engine to work always as it works on the Russian version of Windows?** That would also solve my problem.

P.S. I do aware of `native2ascii.exe` tool in JDK and actually it solves the main problem. However it makes resource file unreadable in Notepade and unf. it is a must to keep the resource file readable in the Notepade :(